# NoReverseMatch at /post/31/

Tags: django, django-views

I am new to django and creating a blog of which while using class-based views, my post detail was displaying properly. I decided to use function-based views and I am coming up with this error. Please help.

This is my views.py file

```
# class PostDetailView(DetailView):
#    model = Post
#    template_name = 'ecommerce/post_detail.html'

# def get_context_data(self, *arg, **kwargs):
#              context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
#              form = CommentForm()
#              context['form'] = form  # Your comment form
#              return context

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = pk)
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked = True
    context ={
            'post':post,
            'is_liked':is_liked,
    }
    return render(request, 'ecommerce/post_detail.html', context)
```

This is my full urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    #PostDetailView, 
    #PostCreateView,
    post_create_view,
    post_detail,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    UserPostListView
)
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='ecommerce-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    re_path(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]*)/$', views.post_detail, name="post-detail"),
    #path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
    #url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)-(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
    #path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    #path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/new/', post_create_view, name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='ecommerce-about'),
    path('commonuser/', views.commonuser, name='ecommerce-commonuser'),
    path('like/$/', views.like_post, name='like_post'),
]
```

My post_detail.html

```
{% extends "ecommerce/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}      
  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y"}}</small>
        {% if object.author == user %}
        <div>
          <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
          <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a> 
        </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
    </div>

<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if is_liked %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Dislike</button>
  {% else %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
  {% endif %}

</form>
```

How can I solve this problem, please?

Comment: You don't have `object` in your function view, which is default in CBV. In FBV is whatever you name it. Replacing `object` with `post` will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Done that and it works. Thank you very much.